# How to show pagination dot dot after certain numbers in node.js & react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pagination

I want to show pagination numbers compressed like `1,2,3 ... 56, 57`, please see this attached screenshot of my current situation and what I am expecting

[image]

below are my API codes and frontend codes which have been done for pictures showing.

```js
// Backend

const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalPages / limit);
res.send({
  posts,
  totalPages,
});

// Output

totalPages = 107;
posts = 2140;

// Frontend

const pager = () => {
  const paginate = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    // console.log('000')
    paginate.push(
      <Link href={`?page=${i}`} key={i}>
        <a>{i}</a>
      </Link>
    );
  }
  return paginate;
};
```

I think I can explain what I want but if you have any confusion please let me know in the comment.

Thanks in advance.

**Update based on answer**

[image]

Please see this screenshot, after `3` should come `4, 5` then `...` and so on.

Based on @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier if you try with the NPM package because you have done the backend fully and for the frontend, you may try with this like the below link

NPM [next-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pagination)

And the demo is [here](https://etchteam.github.io/next-pagination/)

Code example like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Pagination from 'next-pagination'

class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Pagination total={1000} />
    }
}
```

and the output is

[image]

By the way, you may visit the package manager link for full details.

I think it may help.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your conditions accordingly. And for a better navigation experience, you should probably also consider the current page and add at least the page before and after that to your navigation. Like `1 2 3  ...  56 57 58 ... 100 101 102`

```
const pager = () => {
  let pagination = [], i = 1;
  
  while (i <= totalPages) {
    if (i <= 3 || //the first three pages
        i >= totalPages - 2 || //the last three pages
        i >= currentPage - 1 && i <= currentPage + 1) { //the currentPage, the page before and after
      pagination.push(
        <Link href={`?page=${i}`} key={i}> 
          <a>{i}</a> 
        </Link>
      );
      i++;
    } else { //any other page should be represented by ...
      pagination.push(<div>...</div>);
      //jump to the next page to be linked in the navigation
      i = i < currentPage ? currentPage - 1 : totalPages - 2;
    }
  }
  return pagination;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through the whole *n* of `totalPages`, do it in stages. First get the first page links using a `for...loop`, then apply the dots, then use a similar loop to get the last page links.

This example uses a `Paginator` component to encapsulate the code which you can then import into the component that requires it.

```js
function Paginator({ totalPages }) {

  const pagination = [];

  function createLink(i) {
    const page = `?page=${i}`;
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <a href={page} key={i}>{i}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function createDots() {
    return <div className="page">...</div>;
  }

  // If there are no pages return a message
  if (!totalPages) return <div>No pages</div>;

  // If totalPages is less than seven, iterate
  // over that number and return the page links
  if (totalPages < 7) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      pagination.push(createLink(i));
    }
    return pagination;
  }

  // Otherwise create the first three page links
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    pagination.push(createLink(i));
  }

  // Create the dots
  pagination.push(createDots());

  // Last three page links
  for (let i = totalPages - 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    pagination.push(createLink(i));
  }

  return pagination;

}

function Example() {

  // Sample array of possible totalPages
  // Run the snippet again to see the change in output
  const arr = [0, 10, 107, 50, 100, 200, 1000, 45, 9, 3];

  // Pick a total
  const totalPages = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

  return <Paginator totalPages={totalPages} />;
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.page { display: inline-block; padding: 0.5em; margin-left: 0.2em; border: 1px solid #666666; }
.page a { color: black; text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `totalPages = 2` ?

Comment: I know what will happen but the question is asking about "107" pages.

Comment: Actually, the question isn't asking about any specifc number, it just has two examples (57 and 107). But I'm quite sure, OP is asking for a general solution, which will also work for a small number of pages ...

Comment: Yeah, you were right @derpirscher. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your answer and I am seeing it's working but partially like the dots are static, after reaching `3` then should appear `4,5` then `...` and so on for next.

Comment: @Andy would you please check my question and below section where I was updated your name.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( totalPages <5){
    for(let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++){
        // console.log('000')
        paginate.push(
            <Link href={`?page=${i}`} key={i}>
                <a>
                    {i}
                </a>
            </Link>
        )}
} else {
 for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        // console.log('000')
        paginate.push(
            <Link href={`?page=${i}`} key={i}>
                <a>
                    {i}
                </a>
            </Link>
        )}
    paginate.push("...",
<Link href={`?page=${totalPages}`} key={totalPages}>
                <a>
                    {totalPages}
                </a>
            </Link>
)
}
```

break it down to 2 parts. More than 5 and under 5. If you have less than 5 show them all.If you have more, show 3 of them and then a string of ... and after that the last item at the end. You can change the numbers as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

your for loop

```
for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    // console.log('000')
    if(i===4 && totalPages>7){
        paginate.push(
            <a>...</a>
        );
        i = totalPages-3;
    }
    paginate.push(
      <Link href={`?page=${i}`} key={i}>
        <a>{i}</a>
      </Link>
    );
  }
```