# pagination with dots in React using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, while-loop, pagination

I am building pagination where I want to display '...' at certain points. The amount of pages is dictated by user selection; there are 650-ish posts, and users can choose to display 15, 25, 50, or 100 items at a time. Anyway, let's say that there are 45 pages.
**If I am on page one, I want it to look like this:**

1 2 3 ... 45

**if I am on page 3, I want it to look like this:**

1 ... 2 3 4 ... 45

**if I am on page 44 (or 45), I want it to look like this:**

1... 43 44 45

I am doing this all with JS, I'm not using any extra pagination packages from React. Currently, I have some functionality but I am getting stumped on how to adjust my for loop.

**So, right now, if I am on page 1, it looks like :**

1 2 ... 43 44 45

**If I'm on page 3 :**

1 2 3 4 ... 43 44 45

**If I am on page 4:**

1... 3 4 5 ... 43 44 45

**If I am on page 45:

1 ... 44 45

I looked around for a long time, and finally found a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298657/how-to-show-pagination-dot-dot-after-certain-numbers-in-node-js-react) thread that helped. I implemented the basic while loop provided by derpirscher.

```
let pagination = [], i = 1;

 while (i <= totalPageCount) {

   if (i <= 1 || 
     i >= totalPageCount - 2|| 
     i >= currentPage - 1 && i <= currentPage + 1) { 
     pagination.push(i);
     i++;
   } else {
     pagination.push('...');

     //jump to the next page to be linked in the navigation
     i = i < currentPage ? currentPage - 1 : totalPageCount - 2;
   }
 }
```

In this example, `totalPageCount` is how many pages there are total, and `currentPage` is the page the user is currently on. I tried to incorporate some sibling logic where if, for example, the left sibling index was greater than two, I inserted dots. That just resulted in there being dots on the left side of just about every page number, and I definitely didn't want that.

If it is important, I map through `pagination` directly in my render function to generate the template.

```
      {pagination.map((pageNumber) => {

        return (
          <li key={pageNumber}>

            <button
              onClick={() => onPageChange(pageNumber)}
            >
              {pageNumber}
            </button>

          </li>
        )
      })}
```

Any thoughts or useful resources on this would be appreciated. I know my JS could be better, which is partly why I am trying to practice doing it this way!